# bash for loop in function with passing parameters

Tags: bash, function, loops, parameters, format-specifiers

i´m new to bash and couldn`t find any fitting answer, hopefully you guys can help me. Sorry if the answer to my question is too obvious.

I want to create a function with variable number of parameters, that should be printed out with a for loop.
The parameters passed are the printable Strings. The output should be the number of the "for loop" starting with 1 and then the passed argument. I can´t find the solution to say: Print the number of the iteration, then print the function parameter at position of the iteration.

I always get the error: invalid number

Please excuse the confusion. THANKS

it should look like this

```
SOME TEXT

1: String1
2: String2
3: String3
```

```
func()  {
 echo -e "SOME TEXT"

        for i in "$@"; do
            printf  '%d: %s\n' "$i" "$@"   # I also tried "${i[@]}"
        done

}

func String1 String2 String3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `$i` will be each argument passed to the function. That can't be converted to a number according to `printf`, so it complains.
That is because `$@` is a list of all the arguments passed to the function. In your case, `$@` contains the elements `String1`, `String2` and `String3`.

This is what you mean:

```
func(){
    echo -e "SOME TEXT"
    i=0
    for arg in "$@"; do
        i=$((i+1))
        printf '%d: %s\n' "$i" "$arg"
    done
}
func String1 String2 String3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func() {
    echo -e "SOME TEXT"
    for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
        eval str=\$$i
        printf '%d: %s %s\n' "$i" "$str" "${!i}"
    done
}
```

Uses indirect references to access the variable. `str` is the old way, `${!i}` is  a newer shorthand approach.

Comment: `func a b c`: bash: printf: a: invalid number.

Comment: HI John3136, thanks for your answer, sadly it doesn#t work with my code, I still get the error message: invalid number, for each passed parameter.
I would have preferred your way, because of the easier readability of the loop arguments. Thank you

Comment: there was a typo - last %s in the print was a %d - may explain an invalid number...